# I can't find any grammatical errors

Tags: tensorflow

[image]

[image]

I think it's correct grammar, but where is it wrong?

Comment: Every code you put on SO should bo inserted as a properly language-formatted text. This way everyone can copy it and play with it. It's also indexable. Your title is not informativeand I don't think it will help anyone in the future. Since this is language-specific syntax issue, you're linking incorrect tag `tensorflow` which has nothing to do with your problem. Please look at  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to write a comment so I just write my finding here.

You are missing a close bracket in the line `history = model.fit_generator(...)`
, the line before the return statement

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a closing bracket after defining history.

```
history = model.fit_generator(
    The parameters you added )
                             ^ You had forgotten to add this
```

This is why Python considered the return statement invalid